Magento Enterprise 2.4.6-p4 update to 2.4.6-p5
Anyone can tell me the steps to upgrade Magento Enterprise version 2.4.6-p4 to 2.4.6-p5?
am I just only run below commands?
$ composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":"2.4.6-p5" --no-update

$ composer update

and then just run the composer update will do the job? Please help

does this upgrade include the following security update release from Adobe?
https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb24-18.html


To upgrade Adobe Commerce on Cloud, use the following command format:
composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=CURRENT_VERSION <NEXT_VERSION" --no-update

For your specific case, where an upgrade to the latest patch release of version 2.4.6 is required, use this command:
composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.6 <2.4.7" --no-update

Then run the following command to update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage with dependencies:
composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage --with-dependencies

You can check out the official documentation at https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/develop/upgrade/commerce-version
Adobe Commerce and Magento Open Source version 2.4.6-p5 include fixes for all the security issues mentioned in the bulletin APSB24-18 https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb24-18.html

HI Tu, I ran this command  composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.6-p5 <2.4.7" --no-update. But I got below error  message  Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.6-p5 <2.4.7, found magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.0.4, ..., 2.4.7] but it does not match the constraint.

Hey Paul, try updating the ece-tools package before upgrading the Adobe Commerce version. Maybe it will resolve the issue. To update the ece-tools package, run the command: composer update magento/ece-tools --with-dependencies. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/dev-tools/ece-tools/update-package

I did try and still no luck. Not sure why . It still showing Problem 1 - Root composer.json requires magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.6-p5 <2.4.7, found magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.0.4, ..., 2.4.7] but it does not match the constraint.

What about this? composer require magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.4.6-p5 <2.4.7 --no-update && composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage --with-dependencies 

I did try to roll back using 2.4.6 without the -p5. composer update can work properly. composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.6 <2.4.7" --no-update && composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage --with-dependencies

I got it. We should not add -p, so, your issue is resolved, correct?

but if I remove that -p5, how can I update from 2.4.6-p4 to 2.4.6-p5? Can you please give me a suggestion? what I can do?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
